# How does 周到 mean "thoughtful"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I'm trying to learn the few remaining HSK5 words I haven't fully learned yet.  This one I keep forgetting:

> 周到 (zhōu​dào / zhōu​dao)
> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%91%A8%E5%88%B0): thoughtful / considerate / attentive / thorough

It would help to understand the underlying logic here, but I can't figure it out: 周到 seems like the combinations of two random characters.

> 周 (zhōu)
> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%91%A8): to make a circuit / to circle / circle / circumference / lap / cycle / complete / all / all over / thorough / to help financially
>
> 到 (​dào)
> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%88%B0): to (a place) / until (a time) / up to / to go / to arrive / (verb complement denoting completion or result of an action)

I get nothing from this, and googling [`周到 etymology`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E5%91%A8%E5%88%B0+etymology) didn't give anything useful.

**Question**: How does 周到 mean "thoughtful"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

周 can be taken as 周边 or 四周(everywhere around).

到 can be 到达(reached or arrived).

周到，as a whole, can be understood as ***reached everywhere around***.

So, metaphorically, "reached everywhere" suggests "***having considered all the aspects***", hence "***it's thoughtful***".

In Chinese, we say: 周到代表'**周**'围四周都照顾'**到**'了。It's close to the English word "thoughtful".

Answer (score 4):

Sorry I don't know this word's etymology. But maybe understand the synonym helps to remember.

As far as I know, 周到 has nearly the same meaning as 面面俱到（miàn miàn jù dào）.
周 (zhōu) is like 面面（miàn miàn）, meaning in almost all aspects; and 到 (​dào) means taking care of it. So that 周到 means taking care of all aspects, that is thoughtful.

Comment: That is right. 周到 means **各**方面都照顾**到**. @Becky 李蓓♦ As you mentioned, 周 (zhōu) has the meaning of thorough, in **各**方面. 到 is in 照顾**到**. Why 周 has the meaning of thorough (周到) and to help financially (周转资金)? Because the basic meaning of 周 is making it circle, a angle of 360°. 周到 is planning something in all aspects/perspectives (360°) and planning it deeply. 周转 is transferring funds to help someone, i.e., transferring funds to make it a loop.

Answer (score 4):

周 - everywhere (all aspects)

到 - reach (attend to)

周到 (attended to all aspect) = thoughtful / considerate / attentive / thorough

Example:

服务周到; 服待周到 (attentive service)

想得周到 (think of everything - not missing anything)